# ASP.NET MVC @html.editorfor acts like required and i want it to be not required

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<div class="box-cell box1">
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bags_Per_Valve, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label-input101" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bags_Per_Valve, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "1", @name = "Bags" } })
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your field Bags_Per_valve is not nullable, then by default it will be set to zero if you do not specify any value and it will fail because of min attribute as the minimum value should be one

Let me give you demo for this. I have a person model with age specified and age is not null

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
```

Now in view I used you same logic

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@type = "number", @min = "1", } })
```

Now In UI it will say me that this field is required

[image]

But now if I change my field to accept null value it will not fail. So changed my Person model like this

```
public class Person
        {
            [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int? Age { get; set; }
    
        }
```

It is working fine now as default value is null for Age

Comment: But the @min attribute means that the minimum value the editorfor can have is number 1.

Comment: Thank you but i have already solved it. I changed Nullable in database property to true and it worked. Do you know if this can cause any problems?

Comment: Please mark it as answer for future reference.

Comment: It will not cause any problem unless that field is actually nullable. In my guess it is not required everytime so it should not cause any problem